# cd /bad-directory ; source junk.1 logs me off!

Tags: centos, tcsh, bugs

I thought I knew unix/bash etc.

The compound statement

USING TCSH!

```
cd /lkjsdf ; source junk.1
```

completes and then logs me off IF the cd directory does not exist. It works fine if the
directory does exist. Why is this and how do I fix it.

It doesn't matter what is in junk.1, nothing will do.

```
cat junk.1  
echo hello  

cd /root ; source junk.1  
hello  

cd /xoot; source junk.1  
/xoot: no such file or directory  
hello  
Connection to vm2 closed.
```

This has worked fine for 30 years across all kinds of unix, until Centos 7 came along.

Comment: Is `tcsh` being invoked with the `-e` command line option?

Comment: Why do you keep including backslashes `\ `?

Comment: Sorry the \ are typos.  The correct line that fails is cd /nonexistent-directory ; source ./junk.1

Comment: tcsh is not called with -e, it is merely involved out of /etc/passwd, and the command is entered at the command line prompt.  cd is not aliased to anything.  The PURPOSE of the is to alias cd to this line so as to create a highly specialized prompt created by source ./junk.1  But what is in junk.1 is meaningless as the problem occurs when junk.1 is empty.  The problem is the cd alias works perfect until I cd to a directory that doesn't exist, and then it logs me off.  The used alias line is below, but does not need to be aliased in order to cause the log off

Comment: alias cd \*! ; source /root/prompt  where prompt is a tcsh script that builds a specialized line for the prompt.  the script can be empty, I still get logged off if the cd directory fails.

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce it with tcsh 6.18.01 on centos 7. It dies because of `SIGABRT` -- raised by the `abort()` function inside `cleanup_until()` from `sh.err.c`. Seems to be fixed in 6.20.00. I'll see whether there's any workaround for it ;-)

Comment: The steps to reproduce it are a) `tcsh` b) inside tcsh: `cd /el; source /tmp` => Aborted.